# Error : There is no clipping info for given tab

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-devtools, clipping

on Chrome developer tools

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: There is no clipping info for given tab
at E._handleResponsePromise (commons.js:1)
at E._handleDispatchResponse (commons.js:1)
at E._handleMessage (commons.js:1)
at _listener (commons.js:1)
at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (VM250 extensions::event_bindings:403)
at Event.publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:138:26)
at EventImpl.dispatch_ (VM250 extensions::event_bindings:387)
at EventImpl.dispatch (VM250 extensions::event_bindings:409)
at Event.publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:138:26)
at messageListener (VM257 extensions::messaging:240)
```

I have no idea what this error really is about.
also no result in Google... Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 8):

It's raised by Evernote Web Clipper

Disable this extension will make chrome get rid of this error.